# Algorithm to create graphics from scribble

Tags: machine-learning, object-recognition

I want to implement a system that takes as input scribbles (i.e. drawings with writings on paper, input to the algorithm is a photo of this) and outputs the forms / writings e.g. in Powerpoint.

What it the best algorithm to detect forms (e.g. this is a circle, this is a box, this is handwritten text and it writes xyz)? There will be multiple forms and writings within a single input scribble / photo.

Thanks for any hints!

Update: Here is an example of a typical scribble. In this case conversion target would be powerpoint

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some example images of these scribbles please?

Comment: @Icyblade thanks for you comment. I have updated the question with an example

Comment: "this is a circle" means there is a circle in the scribble, or there is a circle over there? Object classification is slightly different from object localization.

Comment: the final result of the process is to have the exact same looking design. So if there is a text "this is a circle", this is to be detected as text

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I try to describe using the photo example: The box with "Headline 1". If the algorithm can output "1. there is a box and 2. its position is roughly (x1,y1) and its size is (w1,h1)" this would be perfect. As another detection the algorithm would need to tell me: "there is a text "Headline 1", its position is (x2,y2), its size is (w2,h2)". So the algorithm would need to give a description of the scribble (which forms, wich position, which size) and I could automatically generate the slide in powerpoint. If there is another more direct way: any hints appreciated!

Comment: I would extract the text and [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_tracing) the rest. Bullets and headlines should be easy to identify by size and placements. Trying to distinguish between circles, boxes, etc. is more work than it is worth.

Comment: What if I want to get explicitly detect the shapes, size and position? (Would use this as basis to access configuration-based form templates, coloring etc.) What is the best algorithm in this case?

Comment: Then you would need to use a feature extraction method like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform I find these things finicky, especially with hand-drawn shapes, but they are the canonical way.